# Supporting Multiple Views on the Fast Compositing Path

Tags: ios, core-animation, iphone-6-plus

Is it possible to have multiple, distinct views on the fast compositing path (as described [here](https://perch.co/blog/perchrtc-custom-webrtc-rendering) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1909/_index.html)), thereby allowing an app to render each view at the native screen resolution on the iPhone 6+ and iPhone 6s+ and avoiding an extra scaling step?

I'm trying to do so, and though I'm able to get one view at a time on the fast path, as indicated in Instruments and by virtue of the fact that my test pattern doesn't show any scaling artifacts, but I can't convince all *n* of my views to work that way: at most one seems to be handled correctly at any given time, and when I reshuffle the views in my app, view that's on the fast path changes.

Ideally, I'd like to get things to the point where all the views skip the extra scaling step, but for now I'd be happy just to hear whether this is possible in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The said compositing path can be used by at most one layer at a time.

Comment: Thanks very much: I'm glad to not have to beat myself over the head with this any more!